# Setting a databound TextBox control's BorderStyle overrides the new Text value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, textbox, border

I've found and was able to reproduce a peculiar behaviour in Windows Forms, in that updating the text in a databound textbox and then changing the borderstyle will override the new text value.

To reproduce: Create a new form, add three TextBox controls, and use the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Class SampleObject
        Public Property MyText As String = String.Empty
    End Class

    Private _sampleObject1 As New SampleObject With {.MyText = "Old Text 1"}
    Private _sampleObject2 As New SampleObject With {.MyText = "Old Text 2"}
    Private _sampleObject3 As New SampleObject With {.MyText = "Old Text 3"}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", _sampleObject1, "MyText", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, String.Empty))
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", _sampleObject2, "MyText", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, String.Empty))
        TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", _sampleObject3, "MyText", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, String.Empty))

        TextBox1.Text = "New Text 1"
        TextBox2.Text = "New Text 2"
        TextBox3.Text = "New Text 3"

        'Application.DoEvents() '<- won't fix this.
        'TextBox2.Invalidate()  '<- won't fix this.
        'TextBox2.Update()      '<- won't fix this.
        'TextBox2.Refresh()     '<- won't fix this.

        TextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        TextBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        TextBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    End Sub
End Class
```

Running this application will give you a form with three textboxes.  The first one will display the new text value, as its border style has not changed.  The other two textboxes will display their old values.

[image: The results as described above.]

I've made the following observations:

1. Changing the BorderStyle of the first textbox to something else at the beginning of Form1_Load will cause it to also display the original value and not the new value.
2. None of the commented-out lines correct the problem if they're uncommented.
3. Moving the text assignment to after the border style change does correct this, but this example is a simplified version of a more complex application that uses Form class inheritance.
4. Commenting out the databindings will also correct this, but is not a feasible option.
5. Putting a new textbox on the form and setting it to be the first control to get focus does not change the observed behaviour.
6. Setting the text value of `_sampleObjectN.MyText` instead of `TextBoxN.Text` reverses the behaviour so that the textbox without the border change displays the old value and the other two display the new value.
7. Changing the DataSourceUpdateMode to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` will correct this, but would also change the behaviour of the binding.

The obvious fixes are to change the text assignment so that it's assigned after the BorderStyle is changed or to change the DataSourceUpdateMode, but my question is: Why is this happening in the first place?

**Update:** At the request of a co-worker, I had added a button to the form, and changed its `Click` event to set the borderstyles of the controls, commenting out the border style code in `Form_Load`.  When the application runs, I see the new values in the textboxes, as expected, but when I click the button, the borders change on textboxes 2 and 3, and their text value reverts back to the old value!

Comment: I have tried your code and can confirm. If BorderStyle (Flat/None) is set from the designer, it works as expected. It seems linked to changing the BorderStyle to something different from the initial value (Fixed3D).

Comment: Setting a breakpoint in OnTextChanged shows you exactly why - the underlying Win32 control recreates it's handle - which prompts .NET's framework to reprocess the data bindings. I wouldn't fight it too hard - and find a work-around.